# Mysql Search vs. Search Tools (CloudSearch,Sphinx,Solr..) For NonText Searches

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search, sphinx, amazon-cloudsearch

We have a classifieds database of 1M rows on which we make lots of filtered searches.  We don't do any keyword search (No LIKEs or anything), all we do is filtering rows based on criteria (price,number of rooms, location etc.)

Since we are not doing any keyword search, I am questioning if we should use a search server anyway?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to elaborate on why you even thinking a 'search server' might be a worthwhile investment.

Comment: because there will be lots of searches on the db server and we dont want to choke the io in the db.

Comment: So really the 'requirement' is just to 'offload' some of the requests. You could do that by setting up a slave database server.

Comment: thats the question barry. should i add more and more slaves or would search server be a better solution.

Comment: personally I am a fan of KISS. Unless you have a good reason to use a technology (and its not clear that you do) then, avoid the complication of adding another system (which will then need maintaining).

Comment: got your point. some people say db is designed for storage, not search. but search servers are specifically designed for this task, so its better to use them in terms of cost and scalability. seems both options have their pros and cons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of search servers will not only search but also filter big amounts of data faster than a database. So, if you need a better performance, go with a search server.

Another thing to consider is development cost: any search server requires some effort to configure it and integrate with a system.

I have some experience with Sphinx and I like it. Now I'm trying to integrate its realtime indexes with ORM and avoid any database filtering. Sphinx will search and filter data, return found IDs and InnoDB will just select data by IDs (MySQL and especially InnoDB tables do it really fast).

Just ask yourself "Will DB performance be enough for us?" and make a decision.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common MySQL question because MySQL full text search is extremely poor and feature limited for a number of reasons. Just about any of the other search technologies that you mentioned will be a dramatic boost in search functionality, capability, and speed. The downside is that you have to maintain a separate system and keep the index in sync which can be a pain / expensive / error prone.

This is actually one area where PostgreSQL really shines because it's built in search capabilities are extensive, highly configurable, and very very fast. Plus keeping the index up to date can be done with a simple database trigger.

If search is a big part of your system AND everything you're searching is IN the database then a move to PG might make a lot more sense than learning/maintaining a dedicated search engine.